# Javascript: How to encode a string (ex: "foo bar") to int representation?

Tags: javascript, encode

I want to write a function that will encode / decode a string to an int value. The purpose of this is so that I can encrypt text using RSA encryption / decryption methods that I wrote that are limited to only integers.

Basically what I want is something like:

```
encode("foo bar") // ex output: 488929774 
decode(488929774) // ex output: "foo bar"
```

Comment: Hint: encryption works on *bit streams*. (Which you could also treat as integers, but usually don't, as computers are bad at arbitrary-precision arithmetic)

Comment: This appears to be an [X/Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to achieve? What do you _need_ this for?

Comment: Well, all a string is is a bunch of Unicode data points, which are themselves integers. You'll need to do the work of putting the numbers together into a single integer that can be broken back into Unicode data points and thereafter into a string.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Do they work on arbitrarily large integers? I doubt so. Which is why text-to-int encoding won't work, and the whole approach is broken.

Comment: @Bergi yep, I hear you. This sounds like a solution in search of a problem...

Answer (score 0):

**You approach has major issues, you should encode character by character, instead of trying to encode a numerical representation of the whole string**

> A string is a sequence of characters, using some character encoding. Characters can be represented with integers, in consequence you would be able to concatenate those integers, and generate an integer that represents the whole string. But the size of that resulting integer would be impossible to handle.

I'm going to expose what would happen if you try to convert a string into its numerical representation ( a sequence of char codes with proper padding )

If you convert each character into its UTF-16 numerical representation using `str.charCodeAt(index)`, which can represent a value from 0 to 65535 (5 digits), you will get Numbers with different length.

Eg: `'a'.charCodeAt(0) = 97`  // 2 digits

Eg: `'w'.charCodeAt(0) = 119`  // 3 digits

Each character representation needs to have the same length, so has to be converted back to a String, and sometimes prefixed with some padding, using zeroes (0).

Eg : `97  = '00097'`  // length :5

Eg : `119 = '00119'` // length :5

If you concatenate those padded charCodes, you get a long numerical string, that  can be converted back to an Integer.

Eg : `'aw' = '0009700119'` => `Number('0009700119') = 9700119`

> At this point you should already been able to see the problem you will encounter : **Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER**

---

## Demo implementation : encode() / decode()

Strings longer than 3 chars, will produce unexpected results...

```js
function encode(myString){
  let resultStr = '';
  for(let i=0; i<myString.length;i++){
      let str = String(myString.charCodeAt(i));
      for(let a=0;a<5-str.length;a++) resultStr+=0;
      resultStr+=str;
  }
  return Number( resultStr );
}

function decode(myInt){
  let myIntStr = String(myInt);
  let padding = 5- (myIntStr.length % 5);
  for(let i=0; i < padding; i++){
    myIntStr = '0' + myIntStr;
  }
  let chars = myIntStr.match(new RegExp('.{1,'+5+'}(?=(.{'+5+'})+(?!.))|.{1,'+5+'}$', 'g'))
  
  let myStr ='';
  for(let i=0; i < chars.length; i++){
    myStr += String.fromCharCode( chars[i] );
  }
  
  return myStr;

}

let myString= window.prompt('insert string to encode');
let encoded = encode(myString);
console.log('Encoded:', encoded )
let decoded = decode(encoded);
console.log('Decoded:', decoded)
```

> The longer gets the String, the bigger gets the resulting integer. And you will fast reach the maximum numeric value representable in JavaScript.

Comment: That converts the string to an array of integers (which it, underlying, already is), not to a single integer